# ldapsearch where we need to find users created/updated in openDJ like from specific time

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, openam, opendj

Can you please help with ldapsearch where we need to find users created/updated in openDJ like from lastweek/yesterday .Basically looking for a filter that pull up users that got updated like password ..etc after certain date

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the LDAP Server Implementation which attributes are used (or even if they are available) 
Something like this?

Created:

```
(&(createTimestamp>=20070101000000Z)(createTimestamp<=20170101000000Z))
```

Modified

```
(&(ModifyTimestamp>=20070101000000Z)(ModifyTimestamp<=20170101000000Z))
```

Password Changed Time

```
(&(PwdChangedTime>=20070101000000Z)(PwdChangedTime<=20170101000000Z))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried these commands but none of these are working. Can you please let me know how to check are these attributes are used or not during implementation . Because i have not installed OpenDJ.

Comment: Well, OpenDJ does use and set those attributes automatically for all entries that are created or updated over LDAP. These first 2 attributes are standards and part of the LDAPv3 specifications, so they should be available on all servers. Because they are operational, they may not be returned with the entries, unless explicitly requested. The 3rd one (PwdChangedTime) will only be available on servers that implement the LDAP Password Policy internet draft. OpenDJ and OpenLDAP do.